# RSpec any_args matcher failing with wrong number of arguments?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-mocks

I've added the following allow statement to spec_helper.rb to fix an issue in my codebase where tons of specs had added expect().receive on the metrics class making tests brittle to new metrics calls in underlying classes.

```
allow(MetricsClass).to receive(:increment).with(any_args)
```

Unfortunately, I'm running in errors

> ```
>  ArgumentError:
>    Wrong number of arguments. Expected 1, got 2.
> ```

The function definition:

```
def self.increment(counter_name, by: 1, **tags)
```

The line in the code where this failure happens:

```
  MetricsClass.increment("string", **info)
```

Info itself is a hash

```
puts info
{"class/method"=>true}
```

ruby 2.7.6
rspec 3.12.0

Relevant RSpec configuration:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
     mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

Comment: I've been noodling around a bit more since I posted this and I'm thinking something in rspec isn't playing nice with the / in the hash key.

Comment: [Works For Me™](https://gist.github.com/schwern/09c12fa1de47280ea9350ae7d3eecafd). Note that you should probably use `with(instance_of(String), any_args)`.

Comment: Note that a Hash with String keys seems like data and probably shouldn't be passed in as `**splat` arguments, but rather as a single Hash argument with a default of `{}`.  `self.increment(counter_name, tags={}, by: 1)` or `self.increment(counter_name, tags: {}, by: 1)`. This gives the method a more defined signature for safer mocking: `with(instance_of(String), instance_of(Hash))` or `with(instance_of(String), tags: instance_of(Hash))`

Comment: @Schwern its actually an open rspec issue : https://github.com/rspec/rspec-support/issues/554

Comment: They have `verify_partial_doubles` enabled. I assume you do, too. That would be why I couldn't get it to fail. Would you update your question with the relevant config options? Either way, my recommendation stands; this feels like a misuse of `**args`.